# UWP C++/WinRT: Asynchronous Sleep

Tags: c++, asynchronous, uwp, windows-runtime, winrt-async

How can I wait a specific amount of time without blocking the UI thread? I'm looking for `await Task.Delay()` equivalent in C++/WinRT.

```
IAsyncAction MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
   const auto& requestResponse{ co_await HttpClient{}.GetStringAsync(Uri{ L"https://pastebin.com/raw/1j9EAVUW" }) };

   Sleep(1000); // This does block UI and makes UI not responsive.
   await Task.Delay(1000); // This would work in C#, but is not a thing in C++.

   myButton().Content(box_value(requestResponse));
}
```

Edit:

A possible solution is to call `Sleep(ms)` on a background thread.

```
winrt::apartment_context ui_thread; // Capture calling context.
co_await winrt::resume_background();
Sleep(1000);
co_await ui_thread; // Switch back to calling context.
```

This works, but I still believe there is a better way of doing so.

Comment: `co_await winrt::resume_after(1s);`

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks! The code works but still needs to be put between `winrt::apartment_context ui_thread;` and `co_await ui_thread;`. Is it intended behavior?

Comment: Yes. `resume_after` resumes on a non-UI thread, so if you want to get back to a UI thread, you need to `co_await` back to it.

Comment: Two questions / comments: you already awaited the web response... Why the second wait? Also, your button handler is re-entrant since you don't disable it.

Comment: @Peter Torr - MSFT, this is just a test/example code. In the real scenario I am going to periodically pool a website every X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to work in a separate thread by submitting a work item to the thread pool, which can maintain a responsive UI while still completing work that takes a noticeable amount of time. Refer to the document for more information about how to [submit a work item to the thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/submit-a-work-item-to-the-thread-pool).

You could check the following as a sample:

```
IAsyncAction MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    co_await Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync([&](Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction const& workItem)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
    });
    myButton().Content(box_value(L"Clicked"));
}
```